Is it really not possible to undo a system update on Switch?
At the moment, I can not transfer images from Switch to my Linux boxes (the Switch is telling me to connect to my PC but it already is).
To check if it is a problem with the newest Switch firmware or a problem with my USB connector, I was searching if I could undo the latest Switch software update.

I don't think any gaming console has an official way to downgrade to a previous version of the software.

This is bad. As Long i did not know hardware issue or not i can not Bring it back to the Store.

@TimmyJim The PS4 and PS5 allows you to download the system software files from Sony's website to a USB and manually install to the system (I did this when I upgraded the internal hard drive). Theoretically, if one saved pervious install files, you could re-install a previous version

@Wondercricket I'm kind of shocked that's a thing.

The switch is really closed source :D.

Assuming you have not modified the Switch, it blows fuses to keep track of the most recent update installed, and refuses to run if it sees "too many" blown fuses. Blowing fuses is a permanent alteration of the hardware, so you would have to modify the software or firmware to prevent the Switch from "noticing" that you downgraded it.
Not every system update will necessarily blow a fuse (there are only so many fuses in the whole Switch), and of course homebrewers have found ways around this problem, but I think it illustrates the broader point: Nintendo really, really does not want you downgrading your Switch under any circumstances.
If all you want to do is move a few screenshots over, the easiest option is to get an SD card and a card reader. Homebrew is generally a lot more complicated than that, so it's probably not an ideal solution for most users.

"What the [redacted]"..... Am I correct in my understanding that this means that in the very remote scenario of a bad update that bricks the system (actual bug or malicious actor) every updated system would be permanently unusable, without any chance for a "factory reset"? Seems a really awesome way to set you a single failure point that could easily enough put you out of business with all the replacement costs. Now we know that in order to destroy Nintendo competition, Sony / Microsoft have just to find one single kamikaze mole dev...

@Ꮢedacted, assuming that single kamikaze mole dev has the power to push system updates without any testing or approval whatsoever. Personally, I'm more interested in the event where they run out of fuses, only to realize the current firmware has a flaw that makes modding super easy.

@Nolonar the mole would just need to poison the update after it was approved. Not very probable but not impossible at all, worse things happened.

Holy - no way does it actually damage itself on purpose in the name of software upgrades.

@TimmyJim it's a component specifically designed for that purpose, so it's not really damage.
